# Wiriting 'JSON.stringify' generates an error when Vue component loads

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am writing a Vue plugin, but anytime I try to add `JSON.stringify` to it I get a runtime error in the browser and the page goes blank. Anywhere in the Plugin file I write `JSON.stringify` I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

If I write JSON.stringify to a component directly (in the 'created' lifecycle hook, for example), nothing happens.

This is not an error during the webpack compilation, it happens only in the browser inside an `eval`. The line where the error occurs looks like this:

```
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__ ....")
```

This is what is written in the plugin file

```
var MyPlugin = function () {

}

JSON.stringify({})
MyPlugin.secret = 'vue-plugin-secret'

MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {

}

module.exports = MyPlugin

// export default MyPlugin
```

And this is how I get it in the component:

```
var MyPlugin = require('./MyPlugin')
```

If I comment the `JSON.stringify` line the error stops.

**@edit**

did what @Saurabh suggested, used 'import' so I had to change the export form of the plugin

```
//MyPlugin.js
export default MyPlugin
```

And in the .vue component I did

```
import MyPlugin from './MyPlugin';
```

this fixed the error, but what is the reason for this? some webpack configuration? (I'm using the default `webpack` configuration of `vue-cli`)

Comment: Try `import MyPlugin from './MyPlugin'`

Comment: Can we see the object which is getting stringify-ed?

Comment: empty objects, string, anything makes this error

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039